# jquery validator not accepting any input for my name field. WHY?

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

See code below...   jquery validator seems to be rejecting any input entered in the name field.  it asks to match the specified format.  Is there a default format or something? I am stumped!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#signupform").validator();
    });
</script>


<body>

<form id="signupform">
    <fieldset>

    <p><input type="text" name="name" value="Name*" minlength="1" maxlength="40" pattern="[A-Za-z]" required /></p>
    <p><input type="email" name="email" value="Email*" required /></p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of values are you entering?

Comment: Remove the asterix from your value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `[A-Za-z]` matches a ***single*** character, thus if you type more than one, you'll get a validation error. Use `[A-Za-z]+` instead, which means *one or more* characters in the range `A-Z` or `a-z`.

Also, this pattern won't match the initial value `Name*` due to the asterisk.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed.  Do you know of a good site/tutorial for the pattern attribute?  I can't seem to find one...

Comment: Pattern attribute just takes a regular expression. Best site to learn about RegExp http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: @user1537688: You're welcome. The pattern attribute uses what is called a regular expression, it's a very powerful tool. You can start by reading the article on Wikipedia about it, and if you want to know more advanced stuff, check this site http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html.